# How to store resource file with same name but different extensions in android

Tags: android, media-player, android-resources

I am working on one static custom Android Media Player Application where i have many media files stored in `raw` folder.
Where **as some files have same name but different extensions, here android is giving me
res\raw\then.mp4:0: error: Resource entry then is already defined. 
res\raw\then.mp3:0: Originally defined here..**

Can anybody please suggest me something on this?

Also there are few media files with java keywords like `if, else, return, switch, case,class, else, final, long, new, this,true`... **where android is giving me error of invalid symbol**.

Please suggest me solution for that also.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can use assets directory with subfolders thats the easiest approach

Answer (score 3):

As @blackbelt said, it's not possible, I'll just add that you can instead put your files in the assets directory instead of res.
You will not be able to use them like R.id.file, but you will get more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

simply you can't. `Raw` is build at compile-time inside `R.java`, and the name key must follow the java convention for naming. Since

> if, else, return, switch, case,class, else, final, long, new,
>   this,true

are reserved keywords you can not use them.

Edit: `R.java` would look lie:

```
public static final class raw {
        public static final int if=0x70000;
```

Comment: Yes I know that , but I need to use those into my application, I can't tell this to client that these are keywords and i can't use it.. is there any alternative ? and what about same name with different extension case? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: in either cases you can not. You can move it inside the `assets` folder

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I have tried it earlier but the thing is I need to maintain too many validations for that as there are thousands of audio and video and among them hundreds of there with same name.

Comment: Not sure I understand the difference in maintaining it, but that's probably a different question already :)